# android recyclerview gridview item not showing properly

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview gridview to show product. But its showing like this
[this is the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXahw.png)

my xml view code is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cover_height"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:elevation="7dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:riv_oval="false"
            app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="6dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="6dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cover_height"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <pseudozero.smalam.com.finwallet.utils.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/tvProductTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Wrist Watch"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:customFont="fonts/Proxima_Nova_Bold.otf"/>


        <pseudozero.smalam.com.finwallet.utils.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/tvProductVendor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvProductTitle"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Rolex"
            app:customFont="fonts/Proxima_Nova_Reguler.otf"/>

        <pseudozero.smalam.com.finwallet.utils.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/tvPriceTag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="500 BDT"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/price_tag_back_n"
            app:customFont="fonts/Proxima_Nova_Bold.otf"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I am using a card view inside linearlayout. But I am getting this 
I am loading all data from server. Only the second item is going up. I want that all items will be decorated.

Comment: you need to fix height of image in layout

Comment: I have fixed the height of image

Comment: set fix height of your card view

Comment: I have fix the height of cardview but its showing same :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Use fixed height of `CardView` and `RoundedImageView`
2. Use attribute `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` instead of `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to `RoundedImageView`.

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout Height should be wrap_content

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

And in your code you do not close parent LinearLayout.